# Pushing to a feature branch when git branch shows you are already on the same feature branch

Tags: git

this has probably been asked many times but I couldn't find the exact answer to what I'm looking for.

My question is if I cloned a feature branch by `git clone -b feature1 <remote>`. I've made some changes and now I want to push to the same branch, ie `feature1`, if `git branch` shows `*feature1` instead of the master branch. When I do a `git push`, all the changes get pushed to the `feature1` branch instead of the master branch right?

Or do I do `git push origin feature1`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would have to commit your changes, but I guess that's what you mean by 'made some changes'.
Yes `git push` pushes to the remote branch of your currently active branch (that is what `git branch` shows you with `*feature1`)

See [git push docu](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

> EXAMPLES
>
> git push
>
> Works like git push <remote>, where <remote> is the current branch’s remote (or origin, if no remote is configured for the current
> branch).

Answer (score 2):

[Andy Meissner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63622870/1256452) covers the basics, but there are some pitfalls here:

- First, check which Git version you have (run `git --version`).  **If your Git version predates version 2, the defaults are different.**
- The configuration variable `push.default` tells `git push` what to do when you run `git push` or `git push origin`, vs `git push origin feature1`.  If you have not set `push.default` ... well, see below.
- The last argument—the `feature1` part in `git push origin feature1`—is what Git calls a *refspec*, and that's what we'll be concerned with here.

With these in mind, let's look at what `git push` really does.

#### Git is all about commits

Git newbies, and even casual users who have been using Git for quite some time, often think that Git is about files, or branches—but it's not: it's really about *commits*.  It's true that commits *contain* files, and that you and Git *find* your commits using branch names.  But really, it's the commits themselves that matter.

Every commit is numbered, but the numbers are not simple counting numbers: they don't count up like 1, 2, 3, and so on.  Instead, each commit gets a unique but big, ugly, and random-looking *hash ID*.  These are in fact not random at all: every Git everywhere is required to compute these hash IDs the same way, so that every Git everywhere will agree that some particular commit gets *that* hash ID.  This way, two Gits can talk to each other, and just exchange these IDs, to see if you both have the same commits.

*Names* in Git—branch makes like `master` and `feature1`—let Git find these hash IDs.  I'm going to skip over a lot of important detail here to keep this answer short, but in fact, each name really only holds *one* hash ID.

#### How `git push` uses these

When you run:

```
git push origin
```

you're telling your Git to use the short name `origin`—Git calls this short name a *remote*, and this name holds on to the longer URL for you—to call up some other Git at some URL.  Your Git uses that URL to get access to the other Git, usually over the Internet.  Then your Git and their Git have that conversation: your Git says *I have a commit with hash ID ______.  Would you like this commit?*

Your Git needs to fill in this blank.  The blank gets filled in based on the *refspec* you use.  So, what refspec did you use on the command line?

If you ran `git push` or `git push origin`, without giving *any* refspec, your Git has to fall back on some default.  Since Git 2.0, this default has been one that is called `simple`.  In older version of Git, the default was `matching`—which needs more than the above simplified picture, but first, let's talk about refspecs.

#### Refspecs and the second part of `git push`

The simplest form of refspec is just a branch or tag name, like `feature1`.  The second-simplest form is a pair of names, like `feature1:feature1`.  For `git push`, this simplest form is just an abbreviation for the repeated, second-simplest form.

If you were to write, e.g., `feature1:newbranch`, the left-side name would be the branch name on your side of the `git push`.  That is, your Git will look up the hash ID of the *last* commit on your `feature1` branch.  That's the commit, or commits, that your Git will offer to the other Git.  They'll take this commit and any earlier commits that you have, that they don't have yet.

After offering whatever new commits you have, your Git then sends their Git a polite request: *Please, if it's OK, set your branch name ______ to hash ID ______.  Then, let me know if that was OK.*  Your Git now fills in *both* blanks.  The *name* part comes from the second half of the refspec, and the *hash ID* part is the same hash ID we started with above.

Hence, we first send the other Git the *commits* you made.  Then we ask that other Git to set *one of its branch names*, to remember the *last* of those commits.

#### The refspec controls everything

Each refspec thus controls:

- Which commit(s) your Git sends: your Git offers the *last* commit on each branch you name, if you name some branch or branches.  Their Git either has that last commit, and you're done here, or doesn't, so your Git sends it and offers earlier commits, which they either need or already have.
- What *name(s)* your Git asks their Git to update, based on the initial hash IDs above.  If you don't use the two-name `feature1:theirbranch` form, and instead use the one-name `feature1` form, your Git will send them *your* name, asking them to set *their* branch that has the same name.

You can use more than one refspec, to push more than one specific commit and/or to make the other side update more than one name.  Refspecs can also refer to *tag names* instead of branch names, or even use names that are neither branch names nor tag names, and there are several extra options we won't cover at all here.

#### If you leave out the refspec, you get a default

The `push.default` setting controls the *default refspec*.  **If you use any refspec at all, your `push.default` setting is irrelevant.**  It only matters if you don't use *any* refspec.  In this case, your Git looks up your `push.default` setting, which can be one of the following five values:

- `nothing`: `git push` errors out, forcing you to supply a refspec;
- `current`: `git push` uses `B:B`, where *`B`* is your current branch name;
- `upstream`: `git push` uses `B:B@{upstream}`, where *`B`* is your current branch name;
- `simple`: see below; or
- `matching`: see below.

The `simple` setting is meant to be simple to use, but is slightly complicated to explain, i.e., it's not as simple as it might seem.  In particular, here, Git tries to guess whether the remote you are using with `git push` is the *same* as the remote you would normally use with `git fetch` and/or `git pull`.<sup>1</sup>  If you *are* using this one, it means the same as `upstream`, except that it errors-out if the upstream name doesn't match the current branch name.<sup>2</sup>  Otherwise, it acts like `current`.

This is meant to act as a simple safety check, and in practice, it seems to work well, despite being complicated to explain.  But I've never tried to use it any differently than I would for `current` or `upstream` myself.

The `matching` setting is the most complicated.  Also, **`matching` used to be the default, before Git 2.0**.  In the `matching` mode, your Git has their Git list out all of their branch names.  Then, for each branch name `$b1`, `$b2`, `$b3`, ... that *they* have, that *you also have*, your Git pretends you wrote:

```
git push $remote $b1 $b2 ... $bn
```

where `$remote` is the remote you're using.  So if they have `master` and `feature1` and you also have `master` and `feature1`, you're running `git push origin master feature1`, in effect.

---

<sup>1</sup>Remember, `git pull` means *run `git fetch` first, then run a second Git command*, so either way you're running `git fetch`.

<sup>2</sup>That is, suppose you run `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature-tall feature-short`, so that `git pull` while on your `feature-short` would fetch `origin`'s `feature-tall` and merge with that.  Then `git push origin` will refuse to run: you would have to `git push origin feature-short:feature-tall` to make it happen.  If you set the mode to `upstream`, though, `git push origin` will push your `feature-short` to their `feature-tall`, since that's the upstream.